# Covariance scalar from matrix

Tags: python, covariance, covariance-matrix

I am trying to implement SSIM [Structural similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_similarity) in Python.

One of the necessary elements is the covariance between the two matrices. Using [`numpy.cov()`](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html) We get a covariance matrix.

Is there a way to go from the covariance matrix to a single value representing the covariance?

Comment: You can use something like `np.cov(x,y)[0,1]`

Comment: I don't get a 2x2 matrix though, when I do `np.cov(x,y)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original paper [(link)](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1284395) gives the covariance calculation as

$\sigma_{xy} = \frac{1}{N-1}\Sigma_{i=1}^N(x_i - \mu_x)(y_i - \mu_y)$

Comment: Where are the "two matrices" in this formula?  This is just the standard formula for a covariance *estimate* for paired data.

Comment: I believe in the paper `x` and `y` are the matrices. N is the number of elements in the matrix. `x_i` is the `ith` element in the matrix...so I guess there is a bit of liberty taken with the notation